# Wordpress : how to hide the main page title but not the sub-page title

Tags: php, css, wordpress

I am looking for a rule to hide the page title of the main page but not the sub-page.

example: mysite.com/video/1

I would like to hide the page title for the "video" not for the page 1.

Can someone help me with it?

I have tried this

```
.entry-title {
display: none;
```

but this is hiding for all the pages,

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the classes you have available in the body tag. If you're theme was properly coded, there should be a function

```
 <?php body_class(); ?>
```

in the body tag that gives you classes according to the page you're in. If you have those classes you can target the title adding another selector such as:

```
.page-child .entry-title {
display: none;
}
```

Comment: i only have this in my main and child page. <h1 class="page-title entry-title">

Comment: Look at the body tag. <body class="">